# Predicting data based on averages

Tags: c#, serial-port, data-processing

I have GPS data entering a serial port on my PC every second.  I have successfully processed the GPS data and the latitude and longitude are stored in separate arrays as floating point numbers.

```
double[] dlat = new double[100000]; //contains the latitude data
double[] dlon = new double[100000]; //contains the longitude data
```

Most of the time the latitude and longitude numbers remain the same as the GPS position only changes every 5 meters.  When the either the latitude or longitude value in the arrays changes I want my program to predict based on averages the latitude or longitude for the the data points stored in between the changes. For example:

Let's say this is the contents of the `latitude` array:

```
2,2,2,2,2,17
```

I would want my program to change what is in the array to:

```
2,5,8,11,14,17
```

I've tried tackling the problem but my method doesn't work :-/ I am new to C#; there must be a better way of doing this. Here is the snippet of my code that attempts to do the prediction (the bit after `---GPS coordinate prediction---` is the bit that doesn't work):

```
string RxString;// where the raw serial data is stored
string mag;
double[] dmag = new double[100000];//magnetic data stored here
string lat;
double[] dlat = new double[100000];//latitude data stored here
string lon; 
double[] dlon = new double[100000];//longitude data stored here
double average;//average step between change in latiude
int i; //pointer double array data;
int count;//counter for prediction code

private void serialPort1_DataReceived(object sender, System.IO.Ports.SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)//activates when port is open and data in buffer
{
    RxString = serialPort1.ReadTo("\r\n");//read raw data from serial port into string
    this.Invoke(new EventHandler(DisplayText));//invoke allows it to call function diplay text*/

    if(RxString.StartsWith("G"))
    {
       lat = RxString.Split(',')[0].Substring(4);// extract latitude
       this.Invoke(new EventHandler(DisplayText1));//invoke allows it to call function diplay text
       dlat[i] = Convert.ToDouble(lat);//convert and store in double array
       this.Invoke(new EventHandler(Form1_Load));//invoke allows it to call function 

       lon = RxString.Split(',')[2];// extract longitude
       this.Invoke(new EventHandler(DisplayText2));//invoke allows it to call function diplay text
       dlon[i] = Convert.ToDouble(lon);//covert and store in double array
       this.Invoke(new EventHandler(Form1_Load));//invoke allows it to call function 

       mag = RxString.Split(',')[3].Substring(6).Trim();// extract magnetic data 
       this.Invoke(new EventHandler(DisplayText3));//invoke allows it to call function diplay text
       dmag[i] = Convert.ToDouble(mag);//convert and store in double array
       this.Invoke(new EventHandler(Form1_Load));//invoke allows it to call function 
       i++;
       RxString = null;

        /* -------------------------GPS coordinate prediction--------------------------------------------- */

       if (i > 0)
       {
           if (dlat[i] == dlat[i - 1])
           {
               count++;
           }
           if (dlat[i] != dlat[i - 1])
           {
               double average = (dlat[i] - dlat[i - 1]) / (count);//average data step beween changed values
               int firstAv = i - (count - 1);//position of first average
               int lastAv = i - 1;//position of last average

               for (int j = firstAv; j <= lastAv; i++)
               {
                   dlat[j] = dlat[j - 1] + average;
               }

               count = 0;
           }
       }
       if (i==0) count = 1;
   }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following works:

```
    using System;
    using System.Text;

    namespace Practice
    {
        public class Hello
        {
            static double[] ldat = {2.0,2.0,2.00,2.0,2.0,17.0};
            static double[] ldat2 = {2.0,3.0,4.00,4.0,7.0,19.0};
            static double[] ldat3 = {0.0, 0.0, -5.0, -5.0, -11.0, -11.0, -20};

            public static void Main(string[] args)
            {
                test(ldat);
                test(ldat2);
                test(ldat3);
            }

            public static void test(double[] array){
                //Use Code from here.....
                int firstEqualIndex = -1;
                for(int i = 1; i < array.Length ; i ++)
                {
                    if (i > 0)
                    {
                        if(array[i] == array[i - 1])
                        {
                            if(firstEqualIndex == -1)
                            {
                                firstEqualIndex = i - 1;
                            }
                        }
                        else //They are not equal
                        {
                            //Figure out the average.
                            if(firstEqualIndex >= 0)
                            {
                                double average = (array[i] - array[firstEqualIndex]) / (Double)((i - firstEqualIndex));
                                int k = 0;
                                for(int j = firstEqualIndex; j < i; j++)
                                {
                                    array[j] += average * k;
                                    k++;
                                }
                                firstEqualIndex = -1;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
                //..... to here.
                StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
                foreach (double entry in array)
                {
                    // Append each int to the StringBuilder overload.
                    builder.Append(entry).Append(", ");
                }
                string result = builder.ToString();
                Console.WriteLine(result);
            }
        }
    }
```

This test outputs

```
2, 5, 8, 11, 14, 17, 
2, 3, 4, 5.5, 7, 19,
0, -2.5, -5, -8, -11, -15.5, -20,
```

Sorry about all the edits I am trying to make sure that the method works with additional test cases.

**EDIT**: Added a test for negative case.

Comment: Thanks this works really well :-) however there is one problem.  Because I have my array setup like this: ` double[] dmag = new double[100000];` there are null values after my latitude or longitude data which messes up the averages.  Is there a way of setting up the arrays to get bigger as new data is added to it, so that there are no null values in the empty bits of the array?

Comment: I worked it out used an ArrayList which solved the problem :-)

Comment: Great! Sorry I didn't see your comment earlier I would have suggested just that.

Answer (score 1):

I would formulate this problem in terms of signal processing. So if you have a signal `f(t)` (which could be your discretized `latitude` array for example), you want to create a new signal `g(t)` defined by

```
g(t) = E[f(z) | t-0.5*w <= z <= t+0.5*w]
```

where `E` is denoting the expected value (or average) and `w` is the width of your filter.

One of the benefits of modeling the problem this way is that you have a very concrete way of specifying your movement model.  That is, how are you going to transform the data [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1]?

Should it be [0, 0, 0, 1/3, 2/3, 1, 1, 1]?

Or should it be [0, 1/7, 2/7, 3/7, 4/7, 5/7, 6/7, 1]?

Given that you know how much time passes between your samples, you can choose a `w` duration that specifies the model you want.

Another benefit is that, if you want a nonlinear movement model, you can easily extend to that too.  In the example I gave above, I used a box filter to do the smoothing, but you could use something else to take into account the physical limitations on the acceleration/deceleration of whatever it is you're tracking. A filter shaped more like a Gaussian curve could accomplish that.